Overcoming the burden of calculations in undergrad Math
TL;DR:
I’m going thru some ups and downs, struggling with some (math-adjacent or bag-of-tricks types of) classes, and looking for advice on balancing grades and passion.
For the sake of TL;DR, here are the questions that I listed below:


Is it necessary to maintain good grades in all subjects to be accepted into a PhD program, or can I focus on excelling in math-related courses?
Do PhD programs expect only max grades, or is there some acceptable lower bound?
Is it acceptable to have low grades in subjects that are not related to my academic goals?



First, for your to be able to answer the question(s), let me briefly describe what I love about math
Why math:

TL;DR of how I got into it: coding → theoretical computer science → pure math.
Discovered coding as a kid, but eventually realized I’m more passionate about the theoretical aspects – which led to CS.
And then naturally fell in love with math, since for me, it had all there was in Theoretical CS but the ideas were deeper, the connections were more intricate and so on.
In stark contrast, I find myself absolutely hating the mundane tasks that software engineers often face in their jobs; it feels like nothing more than grunt work. I want to avoid that at all costs.

Current Situation:

Important note:
Our university (EU) has this system where we have oral and written exams covering theory and practice/calculations respectively, for every class. You can’t pass if you fail either one, which is really tough for me, since I absolutely hate dull computations


Disclaimer: I definitely do not think I'm gifted at math, but I genuinely love it and want to pursue it for life.

For context, here are my current grades:





Class
Grade




Linear Algebra
4.0


Real Analysis I
4.0


Data Structures
4.0


Coding
4.0


Wolfram Mathematica
4.0


Econ
4.0 (even tho got max points hated it for life)


Analytic Geometry
3.0 (absolutely hated it)




As common in EU math programs:

the load is pretty demanding
drop-out rates are over 40%.
classes are proof-based from day one (which is awesome!)


I really dislike the practical, calculation-heavy parts of my courses, especially in subjects where we don’t even touch on the underlying theory.

It feels like all we are doing in classes like Differential Equations, Macroeconomics, and Mathematical Modeling is just memorizing tricks

While yes, the above mentioned subjects consist entirely of computations (or at least that's how they are taught), there's also another category of classes. For example:

Mathematical Analysis [i.e. Lebesgue measure, Stoke's Theorem...]
Discrete Math [ZFC, Combinatorics, Automata theory]
Abstract Algebra
Complex Analysis


I absolutely love their 'theoretical' part

But I hate the stuff that we learn at workshops and have on written exams, because those are just dull computations... It almost literally makes me sick.



reminder:
in my university written exams cover 'practice'


Let me give you some examples so we are on the same page:




What we learn at lectures
What we learn at workshops




Proof of Schröder–Bernstein theorem
Find bijection btw N and NxN


Proof of Fubini's theorem
Calculate volume of a 3D shape, defined as:


.
x_1<=x<=x, f_1(x)<=y<=f_2(x), g_2(x,y)<=z<=g_2(x,y)


Proof of Liouville's theorem
Simplify sum_(k=1)^n cos^2 (k•a)


Prove [...]
Calculate [...]


...
...




And I can't just skip the computations :(

Because the final grade is (almost always) an average of {writtem exam grade} and {oral exam grade}

So if I do poorly in one part, my overall grade will be very low :(

I feel overwhelmed and miserable studying for these classes

(remark: In case of classes like Analysis and alike I only dread studying for written exams / taking workshops, not for theoretical part)


And I really want to do well, but I’m starting to question if I need to ace every subject, especially the ones that don’t align with my interests.

I'd rather aim on doing a PhD and diving into some "cool" math than just chasing high grades for nothing.


Questions:

Is it necessary to maintain good grades in all subjects to be accepted into a PhD program, or can I focus on excelling in math-related courses?
Do PhD programs expect only max grades, or is there some acceptable lower bound?
Is it acceptable to have low grades in subjects that are not related to my academic goals?


Because of this possibly flawed (?) belief that I need to crush even unrelated classes, I ended up taking (still on it atm) a year off just to pass my exams.

It wasn’t that the classes were hard; I just dreaded studying for those calculation-heavy ones.

Also, the answer is not necessary clear to me, since for example, in EU we do Masters before PhD.

So maybe my undergrad grades won't even matter much?


To summarize

I took that year off to focus on passing my exams, but I’m still unsure if that was the right decision.
I want to make the most of my education without feeling sick of the classes I can’t stand.
I’d really appreciate any insights or advice from anyone who’s been through similar challenges.
Also, some tips for managing coursework that feels less relevant to your goals would be extremely valuable

Thanks for reading to the end [:

Too long, even if nicely structured, and the TL;DR lacks clear question.

@CaptainEmacs, thanks for feedback!
Three questions are listed under «Questions» section. I will add them under the TL;DR as well

What is desired here is one question at a time.

"It feels like all we are doing in classes like Differential Equations [...] is just memorizing tricks" Shame on the person who taught your course in differential equations!

Yes, one question per post, much shorter, and we absolutely don’t need your transcript. The idea behind this site is that others could have the same question in the future; your post is way too specific-to-you and is therefore likely to be closed.

@cag51, Even though there are technically 3 of them, they are definitely in the same vain. I could've probably compressed it to only one, but instead optimized for readability over length

@cag51, Also, regarding too specific-to-you. I definitely think other users might benefit from it as well. It's just that the subjects in question will be different, but the idea is the same

Then rephrase it in way that doesn’t give a ton of details about the subject, and certainly doesn’t state your exact grades in a bunch of math courses. You can do it or not, but no point arguing with me, I’m just letting you know that questions with this many details tend to be closed (by community vote).  I think your question could be salvaged with some editing.

How are your peers handling the same situation?

As a frame challenge, I would question the belief that there is a sharp dividing line between dull calculation and cool math. In my experience, the work that precedes finding something cool and new is often either dull calculation or something similar to it, and the difference between someone succeeding with an idea and someone who has the same idea but fails to execute it is often the willingness of the former to do the dull parts of the potential project.
Sometimes the dull parts can be handed off to a computer, but there is unavoidable dull manual calculation even when the calculation in question can be done by a computer, because doing things manually can build intuition in a way that handing the details off to a machine doesn't (the reverse is also possible in some cases, due to scale).
That said, the field one works in does influence what types of relatively dull work are necessary to ultimately get results. Also, "dull" work can feel exciting if one has had prior experience of it being a first painful but absolutely necessary stage of a larger project that ends with some success!

My question concerns the undergrad experience tho.
It's a fair point to make that 'theoretical/cool' results often stem from concrete examples or calculations. I don't mind that at all(!), as it differs from what undergrad students typically face.
For instance, in my experience, math students are often required to memorize algorithms and just execute them in their heads during exams (in my case – written ones).
This is quite different from the process you describe, which can be rephrased as 'playing with [X]' to gain intuition. Imho, those are fundamentally different things.

@quasicat: math students are often required to memorize algorithms and just execute them in their heads during exams --- Aside from philosophy, I don't know any academic area one can study in a university that requires less memorization than math. See my comments to this Mathematics SE question and my comment to this Mathematics Educators SE question.

@DaveLRenfro, thanks for your input!
I agree with your point, but it seems to focus on the theoretical side. In the linked post, it was suggested that one should understand theorems instead of memorizing them, which is indeed what I enjoy doing and what I am doing.
Let me illustrate with an example what I mean. During lectures, we might prove how to find the antiderivative of rational functions, which is cool. However, during workshops and exams, solving these problems often relies more on memorizing the identities favored by the TA than on understanding the proofs.

Regarding antiderivatives of rational functions, the vast majority are learning these techniques and identities for their further courses in engineering, physics, chemistry, etc. (whatever their major is), and also it's very difficult to design "theory problems" at this level that students can be reasonably expected to solve. That said, I always thought calculus texts were a bit unclear about the "big picture", at least those written after roughly the 1980s. See this 15 Apr 2006 sci.math post for how I gave the big picture.

@DaveLRenfro, in EU we don't have calculus tho. And moreover, we don't share our workshops/lectures with other majors

As for good marks, having them will improve your PhD options. These marks will fade into oblivion as your career progresses, but at the current phase of your studies, you will profit from having better ones.
Concerning the mechanical work: Sometimes, you have to go through the slog to hammer out the gold. In fact, it may be unavoidable. Even you made us go through the slog of your post to understand what you are actually asking (the TL;DR is not actually at the core of the question) ;-)
Being able to be disciplined and do things you do not like is a skill very worth training. You will encounter phases in your scientific life where this will be crucial.
The teaching of facts without understanding is a different issue and here I sympathize, as I found that a major issue in how science education is done.
Sometimes it's a matter of time. The teacher does not have either:

the time to prepare
the time to deliver with all the context linked up.

This is not easily resolvable. You need is a good mentor who can explain context; and also you should search through books and literature until you find those pieces which actually help you creating this web of meaning. I personally estimate that in my area, 5% of literature actually gives real insight, by the way it links up with other work, is meaningful and not just incremental etc.
That being said, and closing the loop, sometimes you have to work hard to have a full mastery of the low-level skill and then the higher-level insights will emerge with time. So, your perceived waste of time may not be a waste of time after all.

(+1) especially for . . . well, for almost everything!

@DaveLRenfro That's very kind! If you say where I could improve, I am happy to do so.
